# Meteor mobile-config.js launchScreens

Tags: meteor, splash-screen, angular-meteor

I'm creating the splash images for my app but I've got some questions:

- Can I create of all them at once? I've seen  some repos for this but
  there are not updated with new sizes (e.g 2048x1536)
- Would be possible to use the same image for different sizes?
- My phone is 1920x1080 but there is no splash screen size for that so it takes one and applies a disproportionate image. If I've got
  text on it it looks really badly.
- What happens with the rest of images when I build? Meteor removes the rest? Are located in resources/splash.
- Could be possible to use a html with css page?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Next time you should consider splitting your questions into independent posts.

- Creating splash images: if your image is simple enough, indeed you have many scripts that can generate the different sizes automatically. I am sure you can customize them to fit your sizes.
- Use the same image for different sizes: in general, that would mean your image will be stretched by the device to fill the screen. On Android, you can define a 9-patch PNG that will tell the device which pixels can be stretched, so that some part(s) of your image is not deformed.
- Deformed image for 1920x1080 screen: depending on the pixel density, there should very probably be a placeholder for that.
- Storage of image versions: by default, all versions (i.e. sizes) are packaged within your APK / APP, so that whatever the device needs will be available once user has downloaded the app.
- Using an HTML+CSS page for splash screen: in general, no, but it depends on what you want to do with your splash screen. Meteor calls it "launch screen", because it is the first thing it displays while the app is loading / "launching". In particular, the WebView and local server may not be ready yet, and cannot serve any HTML/CSS. That is why you have to use a plain image, which is passed to a very simple activity while the app is loading. But some people also use a "waiting screen" between some parts of their app. In that case, your WebView and local server are already loaded, and you can simply use whatever you want.

---

**Update:**

For Android, if 9-patch PNG does not fit your need, you can also try to request Cordova's splashscreen plugin to maintain the aspect ratio of your image:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/#preferences

```xml
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
```

> "SplashMaintainAspectRatio" preference is optional. If set to true, splash screen drawable is not stretched to fit screen, but instead simply "covers" the screen, like CSS "background-size:cover". This is very useful when splash screen images cannot be distorted in any way, for example when they contain scenery or text. This setting works best with images that have large margins (safe areas) that can be safely cropped on screens with different aspect ratios.

In Meteor, you would use [`App.setPreference`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/mobile-config.html#App-setPreference) in `mobile-config.js`:

```js
App.setPreference("SplashMaintainAspectRatio", true, "android");
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried to include every related doubt with splashscreens in same post.

Comment: 1) Do you know an updated library/psd for this? I can't find anything like this or maybe a tutorial about how create this psd from scratch in order to save independent images with one saving
2) I'll have a look to the 9-patch, thanks.
3) As you see here: https://docs.meteor.com/api/mobile-config.html#App-launchScreens there is no option for that size. I don't know if I can create my own sizes
4) Ok
5) Hmm, probably too many things for just a few seconds and also I'd have to test the css in different devices

Comment: For Android, the important criteria is not screen size but pixel density (`hdpi`, `xhdpi`, etc.). That is why the 9-patch PNG is so convenient: given the wide variety of screen sizes, you cannot create 1 image per size; instead, you create 1 image per density, and Android stretches whatever you allow it to in order to fill the screen.

Comment: Reading about it I think (if I understood it well) that it's more related to images with an empty background and an icon in the middle but what about if I've got a normal image?
I also found this updated repo: https://github.com/lpender/meteor-assets which looks good but doesn't have support for 9-patch PNG

Comment: If my understanding is correct, you do not have areas in your image that can be stretched. You might be looking for covering while maintaining the aspect ratio. See the updated answer.

Comment: I had a look into that before but I'm aware with this: "This setting works best with images that have large margins (safe areas)". Not a bad ideas for logos but this is my image: https://dl2.pushbulletusercontent.com/ceKXu26mmUlHMNwSK7fis4f2xpigY4G5/640x1136.png 
But I think that is not a bad idea anyway to have multiples images and also I don't need translation so... I'll have a look again into it anyway.
What about the thing with the psd? Do you know how to create these PSDs from scratch? https://github.com/elistone/ios-splashscreen-template-v2/blob/master/ios-splashscreen-template-V2.psd

Comment: Oh, I remember, I moved out the idea with splashscreen because I'm working with Meteor and even having plugins for this in Meteor, it manages the splashscreen by itself and I didn't want to use another layer for this